# Typescript nullable Array

Tags: typescript

I am testing Typescript and I ran into troubles with Array, interface and nullable variable :

I have this interface :

```
interface Entity {
    life: number;
    type: EntityType;
}
```

And I have this property :

```
world: Entity[];
```

I am trying to initialize with :

```
this.world = [
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
];
```

The compiler told me :

> Cannot convert {}[] to Entity[]

Is this possible ? Am I doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance !

PS : Sorry for my english, I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening here is TypeScript is inferring the type of the assignment, and because all the entries in the array are null it's inferring a type of `{}[][]`.  `{}[][]` isn't assignable to `Entity[][]` so that's a compile error.

You can make the code compile with a <strike>cast</strike> type assertion.  There's also an error in your code in that you've defined an array of arrays (2D) but `world` is declared as a 1D array.  I assume you intend a 2D array there.

```
var world: Entity[][];

world = <Entity[][]>[
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
];
```

Comment: Yeah, I understood why the compiler was angry. Thanks for the cast syntax. I didn't know it. Thanks for the 2D Array grammar too. I didn't know this grammar was possible in Typescript.

Comment: +1. This is called a "type assertion" in TypeScript.